# Can't access API endpoints while deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I deployed my app to Heroku, and I have a single endpoint on server.js defined :

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const geocode = require('./geocode.js')

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.get('/city', async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.address) {
    return res.status(400).send()
  }
  try {
  const data = await csv().fromFile('./assets/cities_csv.csv')
  const city = data.find((city) => city['Hebrew name'].replace("-", ' ') === req.query.address.replace("-", ' '))
  if (!city) {
    return res.status(404).send()
  }
  geocode(city['English name'].replace("-", " ") + ", Israel", (error, body) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).send(error)
    }
    body.population = city.Population
    body.hebrewName = city['Hebrew name']
    res.send(body)
  })
} catch (e) { 
  res.status(500).send(e)
}
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

I call this endpoint with fetch (I use react for the front end) like this :

```
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const { addToData, data } = props
  const globalHeaders = {
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  

  const submitCity = async ({ cityname }) => {
    if (!data.find((city) => city.hebrewName === cityname.replace("-", ' '))) {
      try {
      const response = await fetch('/city?address='+encodeURIComponent(cityname), {
        method: 'GET',
        headers : globalHeaders
      })
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const body = await response.json()
        addToData(body)
        form.resetFields();
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    }
    animateCSS('.inputbar', 'shakeX').catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    }).then(() => form.resetFields()); 
  }
```

This worked fine locally but when I deployed it to heroku, whenever I send a request to https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com/city?address=test, I simply get the index.html page and not the JSON that I am looking for. This causes this error : "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".

Thanks!

Comment: What's your Procfile? How does request look like in Heroku logs?

Comment: Procfile is just the line 'web: cd api && node server.js'. I am not sure what to add, I have a react front-end that i did with create-react-app. I get this message in the logs after sending a request to /city?address=test  : (in the next comment)

Comment: 2020-09-26T22:03:24.955680+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/city?address=test" host=map-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1c37b4ca-1a77-4389-a5e0-a28276e57cb5 fwd="37.142.69.203" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1597 protocol=https
2020-09-26T22:03:24.956255+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.93.74 - - [26/Sep/2020:22:03:24 +0000] "GET /city?address=test HTTP/1.1" 200 1322 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.5"

Comment: Can you update your question to include the info in your comments, for readability sake